# Moshi : converting JSON to Java object when the class has a List<Object> field

Tags: java, android, json, moshi

Let's say I have something like this:

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
    private List<Object> elements;
    [... some other fields ...]
}

public class A implements Serializable {
    ...
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    ...
}

public class C implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Where the `List<Object> elements` contains objects of type `A`, `B` or `C`

I use Moshi to convert it to JSON (and it works perfectly) and convert it back to Java. The conversion back to Java doesn't work.

It seems the `List<Object> elements` cannot be converted back, and all elements of the list are converted to `LinkedHashTreeMap` objects.

What would be the best way to solve this? (if there is a way!)

Thank you.

Comment: You might want Moshi 1.8.0’s PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory, which is in the optional moshi-adapters artifact. Note that it doesn't work with Object, but will work with any other common super type. https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.java

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising, will look into this!

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from Jesse Wilson works perfectly:

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
    private List<Item> elements;
    [... some other fields ...]
}

public abstract class Item implements Serializable {}

public class A extends Item {
    ...
}

public class B extends Item {
    ...
}

public class C extends Item {
    ...
}

...

Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
    .add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Item.class, "item_type")
        .withSubtype(A.class, "a")
        .withSubtype(B.class, "b")
        .withSubtype(C.class, "c"))
    .build();
containerAdapter = moshi.adapter(Container.class);
```